# What technique did Scott Mutter use in his famous photomontage "Untitled (Library)", and what meaning does that approach help convey?

Tags: lighting, color, technique, history, image-analysis

I really like this photo by Scott Mutter so I was want to know about the techniques used.
[image]

Comment: "This is not a site for questions and answers about photography."

Comment: @PleaseReadMyProfile It's still a question asking for opinions.  That's an explicit close rule and you should know better than to make smart-ass comments.

Comment: Darkroom magic.

Comment: Mike i hijacked, i mean edited, your question so it would not get closed. ( *maybe it still will ?* ) **I definitely think you should comment on how you feel about the use of photographic montage**.

Comment: @StephenG Read the close reason. It doesn't say "opinions are forbidden!" it says "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to _this question_ will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise." What makes you think that _this question_ falls into that category? What makes you think that there are not relevant facts, references, or specific expertise? What makes you think that that says "only questions about technique are okay"?

Comment: At the very least, the multiple questions in the OP need to be broken up into individual questions or groups of questions. The techniques regarding how something is done should be a separate question from the discussion about artistic intent and interpretation  when such a technique is used. I think both would make great free standing questions, but they do not fit well together.

Comment: I edited the question to only ask about technique now does the follow the rules now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A montage like this was probably made with a pair of mating masks to cover the paper. You basically mask off the paper for 1/2 the image/exposure, and then repeat it for the other 1/2.

[image]